# Get current URL using Python and webbot

Tags: python, url, web-scraping, webbot

Is there a way to get the current url using webbot?
I looked at ways using `os.environ`, but it didn't work for me. 
I need the url of the page I am opening using `webbot.Browser()`, because some links are redirected and change.

Comment: Although the project page and documentation have more spelling errors than my dyslexic cousin's English homework, I expect you're looking for this: `get_current_url()` here https://webbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webbot.html - from the quality of the examples and documentation, I'd be careful to test things though.

Comment: _Mental Note To Self_: Read official documentations before turning to stackoverflow. 
P.S. Say hi to your cousin for me : )

Comment: Probably good advice, heed yourself - SO can get snarky ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use get_current_url().
Consider the following example:

```
from webbot import Browser
web = Browser()
url = 'something.com' # site name
web.go_to(url)
... #your code
webbot_result_url = web.get_current_url()
print(webbot_result_url )
```